# remove quote from output of conditional sentence in r

Tags: r, quotes

I have several conditional statements for my data and I got the desired value within a quote. I want to remove this quote but I cannot.

```
dd <- function(x){
if ( (x >= 15& x <= 19)) {print ("4")}
else if ( (x >= 20& x <= 29)) {print ("5")}
if ( (x >= 30& x <= 39)) {print ("6")}
else if ( (x >= 40& x <= 45)) {print ("7")}
if ( (x >= 46& x <= 50)) {print ("8")}
else if ( (x >= 51& x <= 55)) {print ("9")}
if ( (x >= 56& x <= 60)) {print ("10")}
else if ( (x >= 61& x <= 70)) {print ("11")}
}


>dd(55) 
[1] "9"
```

My desired value is 9. I want this value without quote which can be expressed by a letter like this

```
> k
[1] 9
```

I used this code but I failed.

```
 print(dd(55), quote=FALSE)
```

So, I need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need `cut` or `findInterval` i.e. `cut(x, breaks = c(15, 20, 30, 40, 46, 51, 56, 61, Inf))`  Inside the function, instead of `print`, create the object without quotes and return it

Comment: `k <- findInterval(v1, c(15, 20, 30, 40, 46, 51, 56, 61)) + 3;
 replace(k, k==11, NA)`

Comment: You're getting quotes because you're using quotes. Use `print(9)` instead of `print("9")`

Comment: Thank you very much @ akrun and @ Rohit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have used print with character values of numbers hence you are recieving quotes. Also you should use return instead of print.

Of course `cut` or `findInverval` is way better option than below, I am just putting it for simplicity and continuing with your approach.

**How does it work:** Since every condition is mutually exclusive, two things can't be true at same instance, a TRUE value in R when multiplied it(TRUE) coerces to 1 and hence 1 getting multiplied with your coefficient value. However, wherever the situation doesn't satisfies, the value calculated as FALSE, which coerces to zero, which when multiplied with your coefficient returns zero. By this logic this should work in your case.

```
dd <- function(x){
  return((x >= 15 & x <= 19)*4+ (x >= 20 & x <= 29)*5+ (x >= 30 & x <= 39)*6+ (x >= 40 & x <= 45)*7+ (x >= 46 & x <= 50)*8+ (x >= 51 & x <= 55)*9+ (x >= 56 & x <= 60)*10+ (x >= 61 & x <= 70)*11)
}
```

**Output**:

```
> dd(17)
[1] 4
> dd(55)
[1] 9
>
```

Comment: @ PKumar, thank you very much. I wanted exactly this but I could not.

Comment: @Rokib, Please don't switch answers, You are free to do it, and its your choice. Still I would say akrun's answer is much better than mine. Thanks anyways

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance. Both of your answers were really very good. I was so happy to see two answers that I clicked acceptance button for both answers. I thought that both would show as accepted. But later I noticed that only one answer showed  as accepted. Whatever, thanks both of you again  for your nice answers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using several `if/else`, this can be done with `findInterval`

```
dd <- function(x) {
  tmp <- findInterval(x, c(15, 20, 30, 40, 46, 51, 56, 61)) + 3
  replace(tmp, tmp==11, NA)
 }

dd(55)
#[1] 9
```

it also works with multiple elements

```
dd(c(15, 36, 46, 60))
#[1]  4  6  8 10
```